# CSS/JQuery link hover won't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble with a jquery hover setup.. I use a slightly modified solution I found on this site (example 5a): http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers

Basically my setup is supposed to work like this: hovering over the link element (**#1**) triggers a fadeIn on the em (**#2**) -element. **#3** is a thumbnail image behind **#1** and **#2**. 

It worked yesterday but then I somehow managed to break it. I've tried checking for typos and removing unnecessary code but can't get it to work :(

I took the necessary code bits and put them on **JSFiddle**. I've never used it before so I hope I didn't do anything wrong.. Here's the url: http://jsfiddle.net/kuFDT/3/

html:

```
<ul class="showcase">
<li>
    <a href=""> asd </a>         // #1
        <em> doop derk </em>     // #2
    <div class="sample"></div>   // #3
</li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".showcase a").hover(function() {
        $(this).next("em").fadeIn(200);
    }, function() {
        $(this).next("em").fadeOut(200);
    });

});
```

css:

```
.showcase a:link { width:300px; height:200px; float:left; background-color: #f2f2f2; }

.showcase { list-style: none outside none; }

.showcase li {
    float:left;
    z-index:-20;
    position: relative;
}

.showcase em {                        
    height:50px;
    width:300px;
    left:0;
    top:280px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-5;
    color: white;
    background-color: orange;
}


div.sample {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#B3B3B3;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-10;
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this long ass post!

-Ville

Comment: you should select jQuery on the left panel. works now? - http://jsfiddle.net/kuFDT/4/

Comment: it works for me, you should use jquery as library. it has been set to Mootools, if its not working in your page, make sure to load jquery correctly.

Comment: did you manage to fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You didnt load the jQuery library in jsFiddle, it's working fine after loading the Lib :)

[Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/kuFDT/5/)